# c++ executable gives `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found

Tags: c++

I added the following line of code to utilize the std::conditional_variable:

```
cv.wait(lk);
```

After adding this line, as soon as I start the program, I receive the following error:

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.30 not found`

It is true I do not have up to GLIBCXX_3.4.29. The result of
`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`
does only show up to `GLIBCXX_3.4.29`, but attempting to update gcc shows it is up-to-date. I am unsure how to update to 3.4.30.

I imagine the core of the issue has to do with some library dependency or with my CMake configuration, but I am at a loss for why this would be raised in the *executable* and why it is only raised after I add the `cv.wait` line.

I have not been able to reproduce this on a toy sample, so not much to go on here. But I am hoping someone knows how to resolve this!

Comment: Which Linux distro do you have?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04